# Hive select csv files only from directory

Tags: hive

I have the following file structure

`/base/{yyyy-mm-dd}/
                    folder1/
                    folderContainingCSV/
                    logs/`

I want to load the data from my base directory for all dates. But the problem is that there are files in non `csv.gz` format in `log/` directory. Is there a way to select only `csv.gz` files while querying from base directory level.

Sample query:-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS csvData (
  `col1` string,
  `col2` string,
  `col3` string,
  `col4` string,
  `col5` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = '|'
) LOCATION 's3://base/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='true');
```

Comment: Added a workaround. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

You may not do this at table creation level. You need to copy all the `*.gz` file separately into another folder.

This may be done within the hive script (containing the `create table` statement) itself. Just add below command at the beginning of the hive script (just before `create table`)

```
dfs -mkdir -p /new/path/folder
dfs -cp /regular/log/file/*.gz /new/path/folder
```

Now, you may create the `external table` pointing to `new/path/folder`.